# merge two JavaScript objects and keep method definitions

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have a javascript class:

```
class SomeClass {
  constructor() {
    this.field1 = [];
    this.field2 = 0;
    this.field3 = "somestring";
  }

  someMethod(param1) {
    // do some magical stuff
  }
}
```

At some point I have a need to merge two objects, one of them is of `SomeClass` type.

```
const obj1 = new SomeClass();

const obj2 = {
    field1: [1, 2, 3],
    field2: [3, 4, 5],
    field3: "other string"
}

const mergedObj = {...obj1, ...obj2};
```

Now I have lost the `someMethod` method in `mergedObj` variable, throwing a TypeError:

```
mergedObj.someMethod("amazingparam"); //=> Uncaught TypeError: mergedObj.someMethod is not a function
```

How can I keep the method definitions?

**Edit**

To be more clear: I would like to create a new object, keep the `obj1` and `obj2` as they were.

Comment: Should both the prototype chains also be "merged"? Or only the first object's inheritance matters? Are only two objects being merged or should this work for an arbitrary number of them? Should the first object remain as it is or is it acceptable to be mutated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Josephs answer I worked out a solution.

```
class SomeAmazingClass{
    constructor() {
        this.var1 = "";
        this.var2 = "";
    }

    someMethod() {
        return this.var1 + this.var2;
    }
}

function mergeToSomeAmazingClass(obj1, obj2) {
    return Object.assign(new SomeAmazingClass(), obj1, obj2);
}

let a1 = new SomeAmazingClass();
a1.var1 = "OldVar1"
a1.var2 = "OldVar2"
a1.newVar3 = "Yay"

let a2 = {
    var1: "NewVar1"
}

let merged = mergeToSomeAmazingClass(a1, a2);
console.log(merged.someMethod());
```

This keeps the method definitions and keeps the input objects from mutating. Looks a little clumsy, but if there is a better solution I would be happy to see that.

**Edit**

Updated the merge function.

Comment: Just as comment (not as critique) to the OP ... [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#syntax) accepts/consumes more than just 2 parameters ... thus the function can be written like follows ... `function mergeToSomeAmazingClass(obj1, obj2) { return Object.assign(new SomeAmazingClass, obj1, obj2); }`

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) it will merge it for you but this will mutate your first `object` so to solve that problem you could create a clone of you first object on the fly using [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) like this

```js
class SomeClass {
  constructor() {
    this.field1 = [];
    this.field2 = 0;
    this.field3 = "somestring";
  }

  someMethod(param1) {
    console.log('hello')
    // do some magical stuff
  }
}

const obj1 = new SomeClass();

const obj2 = {
    field1: [1, 2, 3],
    field2: [3, 4, 5],
    field3: "other string"
}

let mergedObj = Object.assign(Object.create(obj1), obj2);

mergedObj.someMethod('')
```

Comment: This works well, but only if you don't mind about mutating `obj1`. It's not clear to me if that's what the OP wants (if so then they don't need `mergedObj`, they can just  mutate `obj1` and then use it), or if they want to keep `obj1` as it is but define a new object from merging the properties of `obj2` into `obj1`, which isn't as easy to do.

Comment: you are right i hope the op response to know exactly what he want

Comment: I edited the question. In short I would like to keep both of the objects unchanged.

Comment: I edit the answer, check it again

Answer (score 0):

Simply make your constructor accept optional parameters:

```js
class SomeClass {
  constructor({field1 = [], field2 = 0, field3 = "somestring"}) {
    Object.assign(this, {field1, field2, field3});
  }

  someMethod(param1) {
    // do some magical stuff
    console.log('SomeClass instance here');
  }
}

const obj2 = {
    field1: [1, 2, 3],
    field2: [3, 4, 5],
    field3: "other string"
}

const obj1 = new SomeClass(obj2);

obj1.someMethod();

console.log(obj1);
```